# How to get a list from nested maps

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

I have the following map:
`Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<Person>>>>>`

I want to get a `List<Person>` that is the value in the fourth map.

How can I do it in Java 8, i.e., how can I retrieve the value of the innermost map?

Comment: So, just all the values? Or something more specific?

Comment: Writing some code is always a good first step...

Comment: As @VLAZ hinted, the question is unclear. Please [edit] the post and clarify what behaviour exactly you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You have several nested maps, so each call to `get` will return the respective value (which is a deeper map) and will eventually get you to the list. In order to call methods in empty maps, use [`Map.getOrDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) instead of [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-).

```
import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;
import static java.util.Collections.emptyMap;

List myList = myMap
    .getOrDefault("key1", emptyMap())
    .getOrDefault("key2", emptyMap())
    .getOrDefault("key3", emptyMap())
    .getOrDefault("key4", emptyList());
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. We should rather explain the problem and how it can be solved.